# Sandbox extension creation failed: client lacks entitlements? for path:

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am trying to implement **view screen capture**. When I run my code, I got some error and the capturing failed.

Here is my code:

```
func saveSelfAsImage() {
    self.lockFocus()
    let image = NSImage(data: self.dataWithPDF(inside: self.bounds))
    self.unlockFocus()
    let imageData = image!.tiffRepresentation

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let path = "/Users/wudi/Documents/image.png"
    fileManager.createFile(atPath: path, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)

    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    NSWorkspace.shared.activateFileViewerSelecting([fileURL])
}
```

Here is the error log:

```
2018-11-29 06:44:10.645177+0800 Chapter3[2375:192235] [sandbox] Sandbox extension creation failed: client lacks entitlements? for path: [/Users/wudi/Documents/image.png] [/Users/wudi/Documents/image.png]
2018-11-29 06:44:10.645227+0800 Chapter3[2375:192235] [general] Sandbox extension data required immediately for flavor public.file-url, but failed to obtain.
2018-11-29 06:44:10.709833+0800 Chapter3[2375:192235] [sandbox] Sandbox extension creation failed: client lacks entitlements? for path: [/Users/wudi/Documents/image.png] [/Users/wudi/Documents/image.png]
```

The log says the client lacks entitlements. But how to get the entitlements?
I google the error with key word in log, but did not find anything useful.
Has anyone faced a similar problem?

Comment: Run a search for sandbox before posting a new topic.

Comment: Is App Sandbox switched on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.
Thanks for help from EI Tomato and Willeke.

Turning off the App Sandbox or increasing file access permissions can fix the problem.

[App Sandbox configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2wm7.png)

Comment: can you show a more detailed process of where can i find that app sandbox window?

Comment: What if you need to make it work within the sandbox?