# React Native iOS Entitlements file

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm working on a React Native app that requires use of the camera/photo library. The functionality works in the iOS simulator, however when I test with a physical device I see the following error in the console:

`sandbox extension creation failed: client lacks entitlements for path`

Based on what I found in the documentation on the Apple development forum, I need to enable the App Sandbox configuration.

This is done by going in Xcode (13.1) to the *project* > *signing & capabilities* > click the plus button in the lower-left under *TARGETS*
[image]

When the dialogue box appears, there are various options. However, the sandbox is not one of them.

I found this S/O post that shows the location of the sandbox in the dialogue but does not describe in any detail how to actually add this to a project.

[Sandbox extension creation failed: client lacks entitlements? for path:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53529690/sandbox-extension-creation-failed-client-lacks-entitlements-for-path)

In the case of a React Native application, how is this done? There is supposed to be a .entitlements file (where I belive the other entitlements should be listed), but I do not see one in the `/ios` directory in the React Native project or in X-Code. What directory is this located in or if it is to be created, which directory should it be added to? Thanks in advance.